# Pentaho log File not showing relevant information

Tags: bash, shell, pentaho

So I'm trying to write to a file a log from a pentaho transformation like this :

```
pan.bat /file:C:\Users\username\Desktop\test.ktr /level:Error > C:\Users\username\Desktop\logs.log
```

But the log file only shows irrelevant information even tough I am asking for the level "Error".. It only shows me this:

```
WARNING: Using java from path
DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME=
DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA=java.exe
C:\data-integration

C:\data-integration>"java.exe"  "-Xms1024m" "-Xmx2048m" "-XX:MaxPermSize=256m" "-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" "-Djava.library.path=libswt\win64" "-DKETTLE_HOME=" "-DKETTLE_REPOSITORY=" "-DKETTLE_USER=" "-DKETTLE_PASSWORD=" "-DKETTLE_PLUGIN_PACKAGES=" "-DKETTLE_LOG_SIZE_LIMIT=" "-DKETTLE_JNDI_ROOT=" -jar launcher\launcher.jar -lib ..\libswt\win64  -main org.pentaho.di.pan.Pan -initialDir "C:\data-integration"\ /file:C:\Users\username\Desktop\test.ktr /level:Error 
17:47:59,655 INFO  [KarafBoot] Checking to see if org.pentaho.clean.karaf.cache is enabled
17:48:08,019 INFO  [KarafInstance] 
*******************************************************************************
*** Karaf Instance Number: 2 at C:\data-integration\.\system\karaf\caches\p ***
***   an\data-1                                                             ***
*** FastBin Provider Port:52902                                             ***
*** Karaf Port:8803                                                         ***
*** OSGI Service Port:9052                                                  ***
*******************************************************************************
```

Any help?

Comment: @antonis Santos Try this one.                                                                                               Pan.bat /file:C:\Users\Lenovo\Downloads\testingdim.ktr /level:Basic C:\Users\Lenovo\Downloads\testingdim.log 2> C:\Users\Lenovo\Downloads\testingdim_error.log

Comment: @karanarora Thank you! it solved